# How to make all abbrev table case sensitive?

Tags: abbrev

I know that I can use

`(abbrev-table-put c++-mode-abbrev-table :case-fixed t)`

to make one abbrev table to be case sensitive. But how can I make this default for all abbrev-tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(dolist (table abbrev-table-name-list)
    (abbrev-table-put (symbol-value table) :case-fixed t))
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer of it resolves your problem so we can mark this post as completed.

Comment: this works, it makes the existing tables case-sensitive, however, new abbrevs created with `C-x a i g` are created using all lowercase for the unexpanded value.